# Django elasticsearch DSL with custom model fields (hashid field)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, hashids

I have a model that uses [django hashid](https://pypi.org/project/django-hashid-field/) fields for the `id`.

```
class Artwork(Model):

    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True, min_length=8, alphabet="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

    title = ....
```

This is the related item of another model

```
class ArtworkFeedItem(FeedItem):
    artwork = models.OneToOneField('artwork.Artwork', related_name='artwork_feeditem', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I'm trying to setup [django elasticsearch dsl] (https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl) and to that end have the `Document`

```
@registry.register_document
class ArtworkFeedItemDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        name = 'feed'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0
        }

    artwork = fields.ObjectField(
        properties={
            'id': fields.TextField(),
            'title': fields.TextField(
                attr='title',
                fields={
                    'suggest': fields.Completion(),
                }
            )
        }

    )

    class Django:
        model = ArtworkFeedItem
        fields = []
        related_models = [Artwork]
```

However, when I try to `rebuild` indices with `python manage.py search_index --rebuild` I get the following exception

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'index': {'_id': Hashid(135): l2vylzm9, '_index': 'feed'}}, TypeError("Unable to serialize Hashid(135): l2vylzm9 (type: <class 'hashid_field.hashid.Hashid'>)",))
```

Django elasticsearch dsl clearly does not know what to do with such a hashid field.

I thought maybe I could just make my own `HashIdField` like

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Field
class HashIdField(Field):
    """
    Custom DSL field to support HashIds
    """

    name = "hashid"

    def _serialize(self, data):
        return data.hashid
```

then use it in `'id': HashIdField`, but this gave me yet another exception

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'No handler for type [hashid] declared on field [id]')
```

Does anyone know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve this by overriding the `generate_id` method of the `Document` so that the `_id` used is just a plain string:

```
    @classmethod
    def generate_id(cls, object_instance):
        return object_instance.id.hashid
```